# Problems with pushing changes -- git

Tags: git, github, push

I'm having difficulty pushing changes from Visual studio code to Github. For context,  I’m relatively new to git and github — after looking through past SO discussions and other online forums, and tried the following: using git init/git remote origin to connect local computer with github, as well as generating an SSH key.

However, None of these things seem to work. When I type in

```
git push -u origin master
```

the terminal responds with `error: src refspec master does not match any`.

Additionally, I’m not sure if this is of relevance, but when I type in

```
~/.ssh/config
```

the terminal responds with `the term '~/.ssh/config' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Any ideas on troubleshooting would be appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`error: src refspec master does not match any` indicates the local repository does not have a branch named master. It could be `main` or another name. Run `git branch` to list local branches. And the current checked-out one has an `*` before the name.

As to the 2nd error, when you type in `~/.ssh/config`, it tries to execute this file. But the file is not executable (and it should not be), and it's not a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

The 1st error has nothing to do with `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! When I ran "git branch", I got "* main" so I believe that should be good. But when I ran "git push origin main", the terminal gave me "ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository." Could this be because I currently don't have any files on the Github repo yet (i.e. the file whose changes I'm trying to push is only stored locally right now)?

Answer (score 0):

> When I ran "`git push origin main`", the terminal gave me
>
> ```
> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: 
>      Connection timed out 
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> ```

It depends on your context, but in my corporate environment, SSH is closed for outgoing queries.
Meaning I have to use an HTTPS URL (after [creating a Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), to use as password)

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
# if you had already defined "origin"
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/me/MyNewRepo
```

Don't forget to create an empty 'myNewRepo' repository on GitHub first.

You can do so directly from your workstation.
[Install GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), and:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
gh repo create myNewRepo --source=.
```